# What interesting graph theoretic statements can be expressed in first order logic (with just the edge relation)?

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic

The (usual) language of graphs has only one non-logical symbol, a binary relation E (for edge).  Many properties of graphs are not expressible as a first order sentence in this language.  For example, it is not possible to express in a single sentence that a graph has finitely many vertices.  I also believe that it is not possible to express in a single sentence that a graph is 2-colorable or that a graph is planar.

Is there an interesting fragment of graph theory that is fully or partially captured by first order logic with this language? Are there important theorems that can be expressed in first order logic with this language?  (If so, then the completeness of first order logic implies that their proofs can be carried out in first order logic.)  Are there interesting open questions that can be expressed in first order logic in this language?

Comment: The first-order theory of simple combinatoric or algebraic structures is often very interesting from the point of view of logic or model theory, but very weak from the point of view of mathematicians who study those structures. You also have to be a bit careful about what is means to express a property of a graph: by dint of the 4-colour theorem, we can express the property that a graph is finite and not 4-colourable as a first-order sentence, but that sentence ($\exists x (x \neq x)$) fails to capture the intension of the property. What is the context of your question? Why do you ask?